# how to remove only the third item in a list in Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have to remove the 3rd item in a list and return the rest I feel like Im on my way to it, but I get an error. How do I finish this out?

```
(define main
  (lambda (ls)(cons(car ls)
               (cddr ls)))
```

sorry I do not know how to  put the code in as every one else does for racket so it only comes in like this format. But I really need help on this one. the error i get is an arteri block saying I need 2 arguments.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what error you are getting.

Comment: it was an arteri block

Comment: Paste the _exact_ error message you get from Racket when you try to run the above code.

Comment: For some reason the error wont show up again...

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis on the last line of your code. Other than that it works perfectly for returning the same list as argument **except the second element**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in the body of the procedure, assuming that the list has *at least* three elements:

```
(cons (first ls)                      ; take 1st element
      (cons (second ls)               ; together with 2nd element
            (rest (rest (rest ls))))) ; grab the rest starting from 4th
```

The above will work in Racket. But if you prefer to use more standard procedures:

```
(cons (car ls)                        ; take 1st element
      (cons (cadr ls)                 ; together with 2nd element
            (cdddr ls)))              ; grab the rest starting from 4th
```

Comment: Im forced to use the bottom one but it only brings back the original list.

Comment: @AdamSpencerBaker No it doesn't. Copy the _whole_ piece of code within the `lambda` of your function and it'll work.

Comment: okay it worked thanks a plenty :D one last thing, what about this post voted it down? cause I thought I followed all the instructions.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't post the exact error message? don't worry about that

Comment: yea sorry n00b mistake but thanks a lot dont know how clutch you are right now. Your helping an F turn to an A.